# Apply setColorFilter to am image in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android development and I am attempting to set a color filter to an image by using the `setColorFilter()` function.

The issue I am facing is that I would like the color to be like a light blue (almost neon blue) color so when I `setColorFilter(Color.BLUE)` its way to dark and if I do something like `setColorFilter(Color.blue(5))` with some Int the filter does not work at all?

How can I put in a color of my choosing which would be the light blue color?

Comment: is it compulsory to do with java ? well you can do same in xml and will be quite easy as beginner , let me know so I can post answer accordingly !

Comment: @NisargJani I am always up to learning new ways, I am new to Android as I have been doing iphone apps.

Comment: @Learn2Code  there are 2 ways to do so I am posting xml and java both , in-case you want something else , you comment below my answer and if you you find the answer , that you were looking for , then please mark it as correct so it will be useful for other people also !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Java you can go as below !

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

here first 255 is for the alpha which controls the transparency , you can reduce and increase the number and do experiment and you will get it as below !

Here I am attaching the screenshots with code

1. ```
   img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); //Completely apply the white color !
   ```

[image]

2. ```
   img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(200, 255, 255, 255)); //Partial White!
   ```

[image]

3. ```
   img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(100, 255, 255, 255)); //Partial White!
   ```

[image]

4. ```
   img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(100, 255, 255, 255)); //Almost no White Color Applied!
   ```

[image]

5. ```
   img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 255)); //Little Blue
   ```

[image]

6. ```
   img.setColorFilter(Color.argb(200, 0, 0, 255)); //More Blue
   ```

[image]

Well You have another easy way , you can do in xml , you can add tint property to `ImageView` like below

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/IMGVW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:tint="#BA2196F3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```

according to me , In your code you are trying `setColorFilter(Color.BLUE)` , this will fill the blue color entirely , instead you will not control on alpha !